# Vagrant up Warning: Connection reset. Retrying

Tags: laravel, vagrant

cuando ejecute el comando vagrant up me salio esto al finalizar la instalacion: como puedo solucionarlo?

```
     config.vm.synced_folder '/host/path', '/guest/path', SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate: false
    ==> apirestfulescuelait: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
    ==> apirestfulescuelait: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
        apirestfulescuelait: Adapter 1: nat
        apirestfulescuelait: Adapter 2: hostonly
    ==> apirestfulescuelait: Forwarding ports...
        apirestfulescuelait: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
        apirestfulescuelait: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
        apirestfulescuelait: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
        apirestfulescuelait: 4040 (guest) => 4040 (host) (adapter 1)
        apirestfulescuelait: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
        apirestfulescuelait: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
        apirestfulescuelait: 9600 (guest) => 9600 (host) (adapter 1)
        apirestfulescuelait: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
        apirestfulescuelait: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
    ==> apirestfulescuelait: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    ==> apirestfulescuelait: Booting VM...
    ==> apirestfulescuelait: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
        apirestfulescuelait: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
        apirestfulescuelait: SSH username: vagrant
        apirestfulescuelait: SSH auth method: private key
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
        apirestfulescuelait: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...

Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar con los siguientes comandos:

```
vagrant reload --provision
vagrant up
```

y te debería funcionar correctamente, de lo contrario revisa tu archivo homestead.yaml